# How to convert Python datetime into ISO8601 timestamp string with milliseconds and military timezone letter? `%Y-%M-%DT%h:%m:%.3sZ`

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601, rfc3339

I have datetime with UTC timezone and I want to convert it into timestamp string of format `%Y-%M-%DT%h:%m:%.3sZ`. So it should have military time zone at the end.

Only way I could figure out to do this was this:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace('+00:00', 'Z')
'2024-03-18T12:20:53.190Z'
```

But is there better way to do this?

Comment: Better in what way? :) Afaik datetime.strftime function has no convenient support for ms. You could do `datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds") + "Z"` or `datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%f")[:-3] + "Z"` but are those "better"?

Comment: that's the way to go, no built-in method for neither milliseconds nor Z for UTC.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know of a better alternative. I usually use `.strftime("%FT%TZ")`, manually including the Z, but that doesn't include any subsecond precision. You could do `.strftime("%FT%T.%f")[:-3]+"Z"`, but I don't know if you consider that an improvement.